# VBA to Find Match and Copy Cells to another

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to make a VBA Code which performs the following action.

That If Sheet1.Range("B7").Value = 2002_2550 or Text or Number

then Find that value in Sheet14.Range("A:A") If that number Matches then then copy the same cell of Col"B"

and then paste copied value in to Sheet4.Range("f11:f100") till the ColE used range.

I have tried with below code but nothing happened.

```
Sub Match()

Sheet4.Range("f11:f100").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Range("B7").Value, Sheet14.Range("A2), 0)

End Sub
```

Make this as well but nothing is working.

```
Sub FindStr()
     
    Dim rFndCell As Range
    Dim stFnd As String
    Dim fCol As Integer


    stFnd = Sheet1.Range("B7").Value
     
     
            Set rFndCell = Sheet14.Range("A:A").Find(stFnd, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not rFndCell Is Nothing Then
                
                    fCol = rFndCell.Column
                    Sheet14.Range("B3:B33").Copy Sheet4.Range("F100:F100")
                Else 'Can't find the item
                    MsgBox "No Find"
            End If
         
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet4.Range("f11:f100") till the ColE used range.` Can you explain what this means?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: His way of asking is a little inappropriate, indeed. But I think that he wants saying to replace 100 with the last row of column "E:E"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code line:

```
Dim lastR4 As Long
lastR4 = Sheet4.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on E:E col
Sheet4.Range("F11:F" & lastR4).Value = Sheet14.Range("A" & _
   WorksheetFunction.match(Sheet1.Range("B7").Value, Sheet14.Range("A:A"), 0)).Offset(0, 1)
```

Comment: You are Amazing believe me. It is working awesome.

Comment: @Learning: Glad I could help! But you must try understanding the code! Like a hint, try to split it in small portions and test each such slice. I men `Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.match(Sheet1.Range("B7").Value, Sheet14.Range("A:A"), 0))`, then `Debug.print Sheet14.Range("A" & _
   WorksheetFunction.match(Sheet1.Range("B7").Value, Sheet14.Range("A:A"), 0)).Address` and so on... You must learn from solutions you receive...

Comment: Yes Sure i will try @FaneDuru Thank you for the help. I need one more help with this code that when i Sheet18.range("B2") is change or update then this code automatically should Run. I tried and it does not work. Let me post a new question.

Comment: @Learning: OK. Please, post a new question and if you need my help try tagging me. Here or there... (@FaneDuru). In principle, you must use sheet Change event of the sheet where you follow the change. But Sheet18 has not been involved in the above calculation... Shouldn't it be Sheet1?

Comment: I have posted the new Question @FaneDuru. No it is Sheet15.range(B2)